# How to find a Label with Caption = "XYZ" in MS Access 2002?

Tags: ms-access, plugins, ms-access-2002

In MS ACCESS, I can't find an approach to search over the Objects. 
I want to write a script or find a plug in for MSAccess 2002 to find objects by his property values

I'm doing maintenance to a huge app in ACCESS and I'm dealing a lot to find the right elements through the application.

> In Visual Fox PRO, you could open a Window Form by using a USE
>   statement, like any regular table and make search queries.

Thanks in advance fellas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found several excellent "Find" add-ins for Access.

http://www.skrol29.com/us/vtools.php

And [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1359776/andrew-gibson) 
 recommend this ones: http://www.rickworld.com/products.html

Answer (score 2):

You want something like this.

```
Function CaptionCheck(Capt As String) As String
   Dim Ctl As Control
   Dim Frm As Form
   Set Frm = Forms("form1")
   For Each Ctl In Frm.Controls
      If Ctl.ControlType = 100 Then  'label
         If Ctl.Caption = Capt Then
            CaptionCheck = Ctl.Name
         End If
      End If
   Next
End Function
```

Comment: you right, I'm doing something similar in a macro right now. I'll share when I finished.

Comment: You might be interested in this [find and replace add-in](http://www.rickworld.com/products.html) that a few experienced people recommended to me. I don't know that it would find specific captions, but it is generally useful.